# How to Check & unchecked a check box In side a GridView of a ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a grid view.
On the ***HeaderTemplate*** I want to add a check-box.(Text of this Check Box is Check All)

**.Condition:**

When I want to checked the check box, Then all the check box below to this are checked (In side the grid view)
->The check box below are automatically generated inside the Grid View.

At that moment the Check Box  text should change to Unchecked & the check box are also unchecked inside the grid view.**(Like we shown in the Yahoo Mail or HotMail etc)**

Comment: give a class to all the checkboxes beneath checkAll box and use that to check or uncheck the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Check All (Select All) CheckBox in GridView jQuery Script

Check below Link:

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-Uncheck-all-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery.aspx